# How to write a postscript after appendix in LaTeX?

Tags: appendices

I writing for my PhD thesis where for one particular chapter, I need to include a postscript after the appendices. I use `\usepackage{appendix}` in my LaTeX preamble. This is what I want to do:

```
\newpage
\appendix

\counterwithin{table}{section}
\centering \section{Appendix Tables} \label{sec:appendix} 
....
....

\section{Postscript}
This is my postscript
```

There are two problems that I am facing. Firstly, the whole text is getting centred and the section header is read as `B Postscript` whereas I just it to be simply `Postscript`.

Comment: `\begingroup\centering ... \endgroup`, then `\section*{Postscript}` -- the first 'snippet' limits the influence of `\centering` to a group (but I would not center everything there) and the second one just uses a unnumbered section header.

Comment: I removed the `postscript` tag -- that is used for the PostScript language

Comment: Anything else and more specific requires a compilable minimal working document, not just fragments

Comment: Is there anything new and relevant here or can we close this?

Comment: I don't see the close tag? Is there a way you can close it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion for the `\centering` and the unnumbered section `Postscript` 'problem':

Either use `\begingroup\centering\section{...}\endgroup` or `\section{\protect\centering Foo}` for the centered section title and `\section*{Postscript}` for the unnumbered section title.

If the package `appendix` is used (as indicated by the O.P.), it is more comfortable to apply `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}` instead of `\appendix.

If the `book` or another class with `\chapter` is used, chapters should be used in `appendix`, not `sections`.

In my opinion, I would not center the section title, however.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\clearpage
\begin{appendices}

\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\section{\protect\centering Appendix Tables} \label{sec:appendix} 
....
....


\section*{Postscript}
This is my postscript


\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]